# Passing parameters in get query to vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I do the filtering, when I click on the apply filter, the query in the API flies away
php-developer, says that the request should be get, not post
how to pass parameters to the get query?

example for my post request

```
export const filterDate = (options) => {
    console.log(options)
    return axios.post(url, options).then(({ data }) => {
        if (data.errors) throw new Error(JSON.stringify(data.errors));
        return data;
    })
};
```

but if I just replace the post on the get parameters are not transferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in options you specify a param [object](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config):

```
params: {
  k: val
},
```

or by building an UrlSearchParam object:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('k', 'val');
axios.get(url, params);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass parameters in get request, pass an object with "params" property, as follow:

```
axios.get('/user', {
    params: {
      ID: 12345
    }
  });
```